# How to add an AutoCorrect entry for a specific language with VBA in Outlook

Tags: vba, outlook

I'm writing e-mails in different languages in Outlook, and I frequently need to add AutoCorrect entries for one of these languages. The menu navigation to the AutoCorrect settings is quite cumbersome, so I'm looking for a way to script this with a VBA macro.

Having browsed through various Internet sources, I still faced two problems:

- Unlike other Office applications (Word, Excel), Outlook doesn't seem to have an Application.AutoCorrect property.
- Where AutoCorrect objects exist, they don't specify which language they apply to.

Is there still a way to configure Outlook's AutoCorrect settings for a specific language through a VBA macro?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Office applications share their AutoCorrect settings, so the trick is to configure them through the Word VBA Object Library settings:

```
Sub AddAutoCorrectEntry(typed As String, fixed As String, language As Word.WdLanguageID)
    Dim wordApp As Word.Application
    Set wordApp = New Word.Application

    ' Set language on a (non-empty) document
    Dim wordDoc As Word.Document
    Set wordDoc = wordApp.Documents.Add
    Call wordDoc.Range.InsertAfter("foo")
    Let wordDoc.Range.LanguageID = language

    ' Now AutoCorrect configures that language
    Call wordApp.AutoCorrect.Entries.Add(typed, fixed)

    Call wordApp.Quit(False)
End Sub
```

Comment: FYI, `Let` for value assignments is optional/useless, as is `Call` for procedure calls. This is the first time I see an actual `Let` statement in real code since.... BASIC 2.0 on Commodore 64.

Comment: Keep in mind that Word application might not be installed. Outlook uses Word-light for its editing features.

Comment: By using `Let`, I won't forget to use `Set` where needed. And `Call` allows me to enclose the arguments in parentheses, which makes the syntax closer to the one I'm used to.

Answer (score 1):

In the Outlook Object Model, assuming a message is being displayed in an inspector, Application.ActiveInspector.WordEditor.Application will give you the Word Application object which exposes the AutoCorrect property.

Comment: This is an interesting pointer, but I can't find a working solution using that object. E.g. how would I pick the language for AutoCorrect with that object? `Application.ActiveInspector.WordEditor.Application.Documents.Add` fails with "The Add method or property is not available because the current document is a WordMail document"

Comment: Documents.Add will not work from Word-light object model used by Outlook 0 it only works with the current document (displayed in the Inspector).

Comment: But Application.ActiveInspector.WordEditor return a pointer to the Document object, and you can use its Range.LanguageID property.

Comment: I see. So the only thing that is missing is the code to create an inspector in case there is no active one. And is there a way to create an inspector without showing it?

Comment: You can call MailItem.GetInspector, but your mileage may vary as the inspector won't be visible.